# Disabled button still fires save method angular HTML

Tags: html, angular, typescript

When clicking on disabled button, it is still firing the SaveComments() method. I have below code which seems to be fine.

```
<div class="btn btn-success disabled" [class.disabled]="isDisabled==true" id="btn-post-comments" (click)="saveComments()" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>POST</div>
```

If there is anyway, I can prevent to stop triggering the SaveComments method  when the button is disabled.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest and best way would be conditionally handling the click event, like you handle disabled attribute.

`(click)="someCondition == true ? fnForTrue() : fnForFalse()"`

Comment: Pretty nice workaround! I just applies it in my project with a tiny modification: 
`(click)="condition ? fnForTrue() : $event.stopPropagation()"`

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent click events by disabling the element with a disabled `attribute`.
But the disabled attribute only work for following elements:

`<button>`, `<fieldset>`, `<input>`, `<optgroup>`, `<option>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>`

Your code has two issues:

1. The `<div>` element you´r using does not support the `disabled` attribute
2. There is none `disabled` attribute set. You can set it conditional with `[attr.disabled]="condition"`

This is how you could solve your issue:

```
<button class="btn btn-success disabled" [attr.disabled]="isDisabled" id="btn-post-comments" (click)="saveComments()" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>POST</button>
```

As you can see there is also no need to write the condition for the disabled attribute like this: `"isDisabled == true"` which is the same as `"isDisabled"`.

Answer (score -1):

in "saveComments" you can add a test on the "isDisabled" to know if you launch the treatment inside.

```
saveComments():void{
    if(this.disable == false){
       //Your treatment here...
    }
}
```

But it's better with a button.